# backup part of string with a command and recover at same position after use a regex command(optimize regex )?

Tags: c#, regex

Its possible for example remove or replace part of text for example

**first step**

```
\rpartremove1,partremove3,partremove4,\n

\rpartremoven1,partremove53,partremoveh4,\n

\rpartremovex1,partremove3z,partremove4y,\n
```

by this text

**second step**

```
\ra,a,a,\n

\ra,a,a,\n

\ra,a,a,\n
```

then apply a replace command for example  regex command  , by for counting and replace comma by numbered position

**third step**   **this step its only example optional**

```
\ra#1a#2a#3\n

\ra#1a#2a#3\n

\ra#1a#2a#3\n
```

**and finally recover the text replace at the start**

```
\rpartremove1#1partremove3#2partremove4#3\n 

\rpartremoven1#1partremove53#2partremoveh4#3\n

\rpartremovex1#1partremove3z#2partremove4y#3\n
```

**I mean if there is a method for backup part of string and recover when necessary**

**With the aim of optimizing the speed of any regex command**

I  need you to recommend a method for doing this

i need backup  a part of string and recover after use a "X" regex command any regex command

please help

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please share the code you have so far and the specific problem you have with it.

Comment: I mean if there is a method for backup part of string and recover when necessary

Comment: With the aim of optimizing the speed of any regex command

Comment: So you just need to replace `,` with `#` and add a match count at the end?

Comment: i need backup string and recover after use a "X" regex command any regex command

Comment: I think it would be faster and easier to use `string.IndexOf(',')` in a loop with a string builder to build the desired string. **And why, you do not answer Adam question? You want help, but you do not want to cooperate.**

Comment: I apologize for any in advance but ,i response adam question put in my other comentary that i need Any regex command In other words counting was an example   " 
i need backup string and recover after use a "X" regex command any regex command"  , I apologize for not explaining my answer well and my comments

Comment: About your answer phil1970 I think using string builder or streamreader is a good idea

Comment: I apologize for not explaining my answer well and my comments